# How to hide/exclude a list node with DataContractSerializer when it has no value?

Tags: xml, serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontract, datamember

How to hide a list node with DataContractSerializer when it has no value?

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class Order
    {
        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

If Name has no value, it will be hidden but if OrderItems has no value it will appear as `<OrderItems />.`

I'm using DataContractSerlializer.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Unless you are doing -

```
yourObject.OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
```

in your code somewhere.
For which, memory is allocated to the list and it has no longer the default value `null`!
Rather, its an empty list of `OrderItem`

Hence, [EmitDefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue.aspx) won't work if you are initializing the list somewhere in your code before serialization and will add `<OrderItems />` to your XML.

Comment: I'm using AutoMapper and it creates an empty list by default apparently.